# How to retain the matching column in dbplyr:::left_join.tbl_lazy from y?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, left-join, dbplyr

In pure SQL I could do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    A.id,
    CASE WHEN B.id IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE A.load END AS load
FROM 
    A
LEFT JOIN 
    B ON A.id = B.id;
```

How would I translate that to the tidyverse syntax?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
con <- simulate_mssql()
A <- tbl_lazy(data.frame(id = 1:10, load = "x"), con, name = "A")
B <- tbl_lazy(data.frame(id = 1:5), con, name = "B")

left_join(A, B, "id") ## shows only A.id

# SELECT `A`.*
# FROM `A`
# LEFT JOIN `B`
#   ON (`A`.`id` = `B`.`id`)
```

Is the only way to add a helper column to `B` like this:

```r
left_join(A, B %>% mutate(flag = "x"), "id") %>% 
  mutate(load = if_else(flag == "x", NA_character_ load))

# <SQL>
# SELECT `id`, IIF(`flag` = 'x', NULL, `load`) AS `load`, `flag`
# FROM (
#   SELECT `A`.*, `flag`
#   FROM `A`
#   LEFT JOIN (
#     SELECT `B`.*, 'x' AS `flag`
#     FROM `B`
#   ) AS `RHS`
#     ON (`A`.`id` = `RHS`.`id`)
# ) AS `q01`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your B.id using `keep = TRUE` in the join, i.e.

```r
library(dplyr)
A2 <- data.frame(id = 1:10, load = "x")
B2 <- data.frame(id = 1:5)
left_join(A2, B2, "id", keep = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(load = if_else(!is.na(id.y), NA_character_, load))
#>    id.x load id.y
#> 1     1 <NA>    1
#> 2     2 <NA>    2
#> 3     3 <NA>    3
#> 4     4 <NA>    4
#> 5     5 <NA>    5
#> 6     6    x   NA
#> 7     7    x   NA
#> 8     8    x   NA
#> 9     9    x   NA
#> 10   10    x   NA

library(dbplyr)
con <- simulate_mssql()
A <- tbl_lazy(data.frame(id = 1:10, load = "x"), con, name = "A")
B <- tbl_lazy(data.frame(id = 1:5), con, name = "B")

left_join(A, B, "id", keep = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(load = if_else(!is.na(id.y), NA_character_, load))
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT `id.x`, IIF(NOT((`id.y` IS NULL)), NULL, `load`) AS `load`, `id.y`
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT `A`.`id` AS `id.x`, `load`, `B`.`id` AS `id.y`
#>   FROM `A`
#>   LEFT JOIN `B`
#>     ON (`A`.`id` = `B`.`id`)
#> ) AS `q01`
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Not sure if that helps though...

Comment: And if you prefer `A` and `B` as the table labels, in R you can use `suffix = c(".A", ".B")` to change these from their default `.x` and `.y`.

Comment: Hmm, well, that was exactly what I tried in the first place and I got `Error in add_join(x, y, "left", by = by, sql_on = sql_on, copy = copy,  : 
  unused argument (keep = TRUE)`. Will investigate further.

Comment: Ahhhh, just an outdated version of `dbplyr/dplyr`. Works as a charm now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you solved your problem :)